# How to optimize Django SQL SELECT Query on views.py?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-views, query-optimization

These are the models involved in the view :

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title_original = models.CharField(max_length=300,
                                      db_column='titulooriginal')
    title_translated = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True,
                                       db_column='titulotraducido')
    thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True,
                                 db_column='imagen')
    length = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_column='duracion')
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_column='censura')
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_column='genero')
    country_of_origin = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_column='pais')
    trailer = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, db_column='trailer')
    synopsis = models.CharField(max_length=3600, blank=True,
                                db_column='sinopsis')
    cast = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, db_column='elenco')
    director = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_column='director')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    tsc = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, db_column='tsc', null=True)
    tsm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, db_column='tsm', null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'peliculas'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title_original


class ShowTime(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_ESPANOL = 'Espanol'
    LANGUAGE_SUBTITLED = 'Subtitulada'
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        (LANGUAGE_ESPANOL, LANGUAGE_ESPANOL),
        (LANGUAGE_SUBTITLED, LANGUAGE_SUBTITLED))

    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, db_column='idpelicula')
    theater = models.ForeignKey(Theater, db_column='idcine',
                                      null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(null=True, db_column='hora')
    type_3d = models.NullBooleanField(db_column=u'3d')
    type_xd = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, db_column='xd')
    type_gtmax = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, db_column='gtmax')
    type_vip = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, db_column='vip')
    type_imax = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, db_column='imax')
    language = models.CharField(max_length=33, blank=True, db_column='idioma',
                                choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                default=LANGUAGE_ESPANOL)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, db_column='idciudad')
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, db_column='fecha_inicio')
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, db_column='fecha_fin')
    visible = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, db_column='visible')
    tsc = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, db_column='tsc', null=True)
    tsm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, db_column='tsm', null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'funciones'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (unicode(self.theater) + " " + unicode(self.movie.title_original) + " " +         unicode(self.time))
```

Additionally this is the view that queries the models:

```
def list_movies(request, time_period):
    city = utils.get_city_from_request(request)

    if time_period == 'proximas-dos-horas':
        (start_date,
         end_date,
         hours_start,
         hours_end) = utils.get_datetime_filters_from_time_period(time_period)
    else:
        (start_date,
         end_date) = utils.get_datetime_filters_from_time_period(time_period)

    if not start_date:  # 404 for invalid time periods
        raise Http404

    movies = Movie.objects.filter(
        showtime__city=city.code,
        showtime__visible=1,
        ).order_by('-tsm').distinct()

    if time_period == 'proximas-dos-horas':
        movies = movies.filter(
            showtime__start_date__lte=start_date,
            showtime__end_date__gte=end_date,
            showtime__time__range=(hours_start, hours_end))

    elif time_period == 'proximos-estrenos':
        movies = movies.filter(
            showtime__start_date=None,
            showtime__end_date=None,
            )

    else:
        movies = movies.filter(
            showtime__start_date__lte=start_date,
            showtime__end_date__gte=end_date)

    context = {'movies': movies, 'city': city, 'time_period': time_period}
    return render_to_response('list_movies.html', context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Currently this view is consuming a lot of resources in the database and this results in low response time of the web transaction on the browser. I connected the app with New Relic monitoring software to analyze the transactions on app and DB level. This is the trace detail that i got:

[image]

I would like to get somo advice on optimizing this view so that the consumption of DB resources drops to the minimum

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One quick note, you might want to change `showtime__start_date=None` to `showtime__start_date__isnull=True`

Comment: Are there any indexes on showtime__start_date or showtime__end_date.  Does new relic allow you to do and explain_plan on the query.  If so please post that as it will certainly help in diagnosing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of your problem, but my 2 advises are:

First, consider some changes in your data model. The `ShowTime` class have a foreign key to `City` and a foreign key to `Theater` and it seems a bit redundant. Personally, I prefer de-normalize addresses, for example:

```
class Theater(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    # Location fields.
    geo_country = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    geo_country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    geo_locality = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    geo_street = models.CharField(max_length=48, blank=True, default="")
    geo_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, default="")


class ShowTime(models.Model):
    theater = models.ForeignKey(Theater)
```

This way, you can save a JOIN to the `City` table and it can be erased from your data model.

Second, read the [select_related feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) of the Django ORM.

Wish you fun.